# How to display handwriting input in Windows 10? It seems to have been (re)moved

Tags: windows-10, stylus, handwriting-recognition

I have been following two official Microsoft videos on using the handwriting input features in Windows 10 and both appear to have disappeared fro my up-to-date version of Windows 10
(Videos are these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkgeecaMTQQ AND https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAKinFG8W2E)

Nothing in the Pen & ink settings seems to bring this up either.

To clarify, I am looking for the pop-up tool that allows handwritten input to be converted to text, as covered in the first video above)

Any help welcome and thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Steve

Comment: The second Youtube link is incomplete. When you right-click on the task bar, is the "show touch keyboard button" line checked?

Comment: Hi there - have just updated the URL above, sorry about that. As for 'show touch keyboard', yes, it is checked - see here https://imgur.com/a/tWTILkF

Comment: PS the problem is that there appears to be no stylus/handwriting option in the keyboard options thereafter (You can follow my ongoing conversation with MS Support in the comments on one of the videos above here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAKinFG8W2E&lc=z23dyborbrnsdbakkacdp43apauzrxmhnta5wlbhqzdw03c010c.1567741226281780&feature=em-comments - they have disappeared, hence me asking here!)

Comment: Do you have the [handwriting icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhMHd.png) on your language preferences? If not, have you tried downloading the handwriting package inside the language preferences?

Comment: Hi there - thanks for this. I've downloaded the language pack but still no sign of handwriting - https://imgur.com/a/4kqtv1A - clicking here shows 'Options', which I then click and takes me to 'Language Options' and the only choice there is for QWERTY keyboards - no handwriting! Microsoft haven't got back to me since requesting OS Build and version (I sent them to MS yesterday va YouTube thread mentioned in a previous comment here).

Comment: Although it shouldn't be the reason why the handwriting input is not available, updating your Windows 10 to 1903 may make it easier to resolve the issue, since the Language settings panel was [revamped](https://prnt.sc/p50sz3) to show more clearly which language settings will have the handwriting input option. As well, have you tried the "Get Help" app in Windows 10, it may offer a faster communication than the forum format.